# UPDATE a sql server desde c#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Estoy trabajando en asp.net mvc y estoy intentando modificar un campo de una tabla pero me da error de sintaxis alguna idea de lo que puede ser?

Este es el error que me genera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la tabla de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclarar que también lo intente sin los "[]" y me sigue dando error, además probé la sintaxis en la base de datos y funciono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A la sentencia le faltan espacios al cambiar las líneas, ya que la estás concatenando y se juntarían las palabras. Dice "Update rhuesolvSet [est_solici]='Aprobado'Where [nro_solici] = ", y esa sintaxis es incorrecta.

Comment: @Javifer2 Muchas gracias por darte el tiempo a responder, efectivamente era eso lo que estaba causando el error, Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cerrar esta problemática cito la solución dada por Javi

> A la sentencia le faltan espacios al cambiar las líneas, ya que la estás concatenando y se juntarían las palabras. Dice `Update rhuesolvSet [est_solici]='Aprobado'Where [nro_solici] =` , y esa sintaxis es incorrecta